How can I use a different Apple ID for media & purchases on macOS Sonoma?
How can I use a different Apple ID for media & purchases on macOS Sonoma? I have a bunch of apps I purchased on my personal Apple ID and I want to install them on my company computer, where I need to sign in using the company Apple ID.
I was using this exact setup until yesterday, but I was signed out from Apple ID, and now I can't redo this setup. There's a post on the Apple Community forum titled Using different Apple ID for media & purchases on Mac OSX Ventura which says I should go to App Store and choose "Sign Out" from the Store menu, but there's no such option in the Store menu on Sonoma


Really... don't.  Just don't.  If they should be on your company computer, than your employer should buy them.

I keep a very strict separation of my data between personal and work @MarcWilson but this is the only place I’ll drop a sign in to download apps. In some cases I expensed the cost and didn’t have a work AppleID and other cases I just wanted to use an app I purchased. It’s not easy to decide sometimes. Do you have any profiles installed in the settings app?

Could you add a screenshot to your question showing that there is no “Sign out” menu command in the App Store? In my copy of Sonoma, there is one.

Would you please make it clear what the separate Apple Ids were used for.

@bmike The OP explicitly says there's a company AppleID, so that's what they should be using.

I understand your choice @MarcWilson I’ve mixed both even in cases when I have a work and personal one for reasons. I generally advice against it, but have found exceptions and ignored my own advice occasionally. Why not post an answer explaining to all why your solution is better for OP in this specific case?

@LincD. I added the screenshot

@MarcWilson I already paid for these apps, and their licenses allow me to run on my work computer too. Why should my employer pay for them a second time?
Also, you're probably aware of how complex the procurement process is in most companies.

It looks like the machine is under multi-device management that suppresses user login to the App Store. Only the MDM administrator can change that.
